# Error override for successul fail

Tags: error-handling

I'm trying to override and error thrown by one of my command in my script.

I run a simple setup, which returns an error code of '1', which means it failed but I know that it was successful, so I would like for my script to return an exit code of '0' instead when this error is thrown.

THks in advance and don't hesitate if you have any questions.

Comment: Well, for starters: what programming language/environment? I don't have my crystal ball with me ...

Comment: Sorry, my head was so into PowerShell that I forgot to say that's what I'm using. My bad.